# How do I split vector into columns using R

Tags: r

I have data like below

```
device  usage
a   10
a   20
b   30
b   14
c   90
c   80
c   66
```

How do I transform it to below?

```
device V1 V2 V3
a 10 20
b 30 14
c 90 80 66
```

I used  ddply(ds,~device,paste) converted it to

```
a,c(10,20)

b,c(30,14)

c,c(90,80,66)
```

How do I split vector into columns. Or other method is welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new column and use that for `reshape`.  Calling your original data frame `x`:

```
> x$V <- ave(as.numeric(x$device), x$device, FUN=seq_along)
> reshape(x, direction="wide", timevar='V', idvar='device')
  device usage.1 usage.2 usage.3
1      a      10      20      NA
3      b      30      14      NA
5      c      90      80      66
```

The added column `V` counts the occurrences of each unique device, which need not be contiguous in the data frame.  This is used in the reshape for the `timevar`.